# How should we add function inside a structure?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct teacher
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    int salary;

    void input(teacher a)
    {
        cout << "Enter Name : ";
        cin >> a.name;
        cout << "Enter ID : ";
        cin >> a.id;
        cout << "Enter Salary : ";
        cin >> a.salary;
    }

    void output(teacher b)
    {
        cout << "Your Name Is : " << b.name << endl;
        cout << "Your ID Is : " << b.id << endl;
        cout << "Your Salary Is : " << b.salary;
    }
};

int main()
{
    teacher t;
    t.input(t);
    t.output(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any problem? The output is random numbers, don't know what is it.
I tried writing the output function separately, but still same results.

Comment: Unrelated: drop `using namespace std;`, use `std::cout` instead. Replace `char` arrays by `std::string`. Don't use `std::endl` instead use `"\n"`, don't pass `teacher` to `input/output`, use `class` instead of `struct`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: Just as a side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I'm currently learning oop , so before using class , I tried doing it with structure.

Comment: I'll try using class

Comment: `class` and `struct` are functionally equivalent in C++, the only difference is their default visibility (private for `class`, public for `struct`). You can use either/or.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a weird design, why don't your class methods directly operate on `this`?

```
struct teacher
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int salary;

    void input()
    {
        cout << "Enter Name : ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter ID : ";
        cin >> id;
        cout << "Enter Salary : ";
        cin >> salary;
    }

    void output() const
    {
        cout << "Your Name Is : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Your ID Is : " << id << endl;
        cout << "Your Salary Is : " << salary;
    }
};
```

Then `main` would look like

```
int main()
{
    teacher t;
    t.input();
    t.output();

    return 0;
}
```

Also I'd prefer to use `std::string` instead of `char[]` when possible.

Comment: yes, using char always gave me errors, I'll try using std::string from now

Answer (score 0):

In `input()` you modify parameter `a` which goes out of scope when it reaches the end of the function.

Instead you should modify the class members variables themselves.

```
void input()
{
    cout << "Enter Name : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter ID : ";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Enter Salary : ";
    cin >> salary;
}
```

Comment: @QasimAhmed The way to acknowledge help on SO is to vote the answer up.